# How to create a DAX formula to create another column based on the value in another column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerpivot

How do I create a formula in Dax that gives me the % achieved column, based on the location. When it is EU the % achieved formula should be actual*target else it should be actual+target

*More background info: The actual is in a different dataset and target is also in another. Data modeling relationships created to link them together*
Tried using IF but getting error

Actual Dataset

| Name | Location | Actual |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | EU | 10 |  |  |
| John | ASIA | 4 |  |  |
| Steve | EU | 5 |  |  |
| Steve | ASIA | 87 |  |  |

Target Dataset

| Name | Location | Target |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | EU | 5 |  |
| John | ASIA | 5 |  |
| Steve | EU | 7 |  |
| Steve | ASIA | 9 |  |

View when relationships created on name and location. The new measure should give the % Achieved column

| Name | Location | Actual | Target | % Achieved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | EU | 10 | 5 | 50 |
| John | ASIA | 4 | 5 | 9 |
| Steve | EU | 5 | 7 | 35 |
| Steve | ASIA | 87 | 9 | 96 |

Comment: Do you want a calculated column in DAX?

Comment: I want to achieve this with a new measure. Or you think a calculated column is the best approach?

Comment: For the data you show, this is a simple IF statement in DAX. But from your *background*, it seems the data you show is not representative of the data you have. Please edit you question to show the data you have in the separate tables, and confirm that the data you show is your desired result (with all five columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
Measure = IF(SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Location])="EU", SUM('Table'[Actual]) * SUM('Table'[Target]), SUM('Table'[Actual]) + SUM('Table'[Target]))
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you Davide